# Upload image to main domain from add-on domain

Tags: php, image-processing, image-uploading, addon-domain

I am developing an application using php. The application is hosted as an add-on domain with another application in the main domain.

The main domain has a blogging app, but the add-on domain also saves blog posts to the same database tables as the main domain.

The add-on domain also manipulates images (sizing, adding background image if necessary and blurring background image if applicable).

The problem is, how do I also upload the image to the image directory in the main domain after manipulating the image.

Please note: Each blog post has just one image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add-on domain? you mean subdomain?

Comment: No, I mean add-on domain. But I think add-on domains are also sub-domains of their main domain.